# "Persistence xml file was not found. NO GENERATION will occur!!" error in build.xml

Tags: eclipse, eclipselink, ivy, persistence.xml, build.xml

I am receiving the error

```
[javac] Note: The persistence xml file [META-INF/persistence.xml] was not found. NO GENERATION will occur!! Please ensure a persistence xml file is available either from the CLASS_OUTPUT directory [META-INF/persistence.xml] or using the eclipselink.persistencexml property to specify its location.
```

when I attempt to compile my program using my `build.xml` file.

I made sure to put my `META-INF/persistence.xml` file in `src/main/java/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml`, and I attempted to add `../../src/main/java/resources/META-INF/persistence.xml` to `Properties -> Java Compiler -> Annotation Processing` as a key value pair for the Processor options as suggested by [this blog discussing the same issue, but with Maven](http://blog.jonasbandi.net/2011/09/using-jpa-metamodel-annotation.html). The `META-INF/persistence.xml` is also being copied over to the bin/ directory.

What am I missing here? I can't figure out why the build.xml compile is having a hard time locating the persistence file.

Comment: war layout or ejb layout?

Comment: The error states the problem - it cannot find the persistence.xml in the CLASS_OUTPUT directory that it is being run against.  Check you scripts to ensure they move the file for you when they compile your java classes correctly, as they are missing a step.